# Area of confidence ellipsoid when using Gaussian Mixture Model in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How to obtain the area of the confidence ellipsoids generated when using Gaussian Mixture Model in MATLAB?

Comment: Would you add more information on what you have so far?

Comment: Here is how I understand the question: you have a multivariate distribution which you approximated as a mix of several Gaussians. Now you want to plot confidence contours corresponding to some given probability. The contours should mark the areas, where the random numbers have to land with that probability. Is it what you want?

Comment: @ Anton: thanks very much for the reply. Yes, you are exactly right. I have managed to solve the issue. MATLAB returns the confidence regions as scatter plots shaped as ellipses. I managed to obtain the area by using the "convhull" and "polyarea" functions.

Comment: cool, could you post your solution here?